# Could not find 'Program' specified for Main method

Tags: c#

I have this problem where i have 2 files inside a project. One called Program.cs and another called Book.cs

I tried running the Program.cs but it comes up with the error: "Could not find 'Program' specified for Main method". 
Here's the code for Program.cs

```
using System;


namespace Classes_Objects
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Book book1 = new Book();
            book1.title = "Harry Potter";
            book1.author = "JK Rowling";
            book1.pages = 400;

            Console.WriteLine(book1.pages);


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code for Book.cs

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Classes_Objects
{
    class Book
    {
        public string title;
        public string author;
        public int pages;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: Did you change the namespace recently? Change it in the Startup as well

Comment: "This error message occurs when we define in our project settings -> Application -> Startup object a reference to an non-existing class."

Answer (score 0):

Please download .net core SDk after that open VS code, open the folder where you want to execute .cs programs and install C# plugin

after that please try these commands which worked for me

open terminal in VS code and type `dotnet new console` 
it will create Program.cs file , .csproj, obj folder

Create your file Book.cs and implement both of your book code and program code in that folder which should have same namespace name

then run this command `dotnet run .\Program.cs`

The Output will be :

```
400
```

Remember in your code there is Console.ReadLine(); after printing the value.